# Event when AngularJS finished changing DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have some AngularJS code which sets up some scope fields very quickly, but then takes AngularJS and/or Chrome a long time to create and render the DOM. This is mainly due to a few ng-repeat bindings to long lists in the scope. The browser freezes for a couple of seconds whilst preparing and rendering the DOM.

I'd like to know when the browser has finished, so that I can display a loading sign whilst the browser is busy, and then display the resulting DOM once it has finished. What techniques are available for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is providing a great way to catch the moment your component is done loading. have a look at [Lifecyle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). They are built in ways to hook on these angular defined events and are super easy to use(see tutorial in the link).

In your case i would go with *ngAfterViewInit()* or *ngAfterViewChecked()*.

Hope you find this usefull feel free to add questions.

Comment: OP is asking about AngularJS, not Angular. You linked to the Angular docs. AngularJS lifecycle hooks are document here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Thanks, but no joy. I'm using directives, not components. I tried listening to the $postLink event, but it never gets fired.

Comment: Also, it seems that the post link directive method is getting run before any DOM manipulation or rendering occurs, not after...